# Chrome Bookmarks Bar Context Menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, bookmarks

What I'm trying to do is add a new item to the context menu that pops up when you right click on a bookmark in Chrome.

[For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS704.jpg)
.

I've been poking around the Chrome Extension API, but I can't find any reference to that context menu.  The normal Chrome extension context menu changes won't show up when you rclick on a bookmark, and I'm not looking for the "Add bookmark via right click" extension.  At this point I don't think it's possible, but wanted see if anyone has any ideas.

Alternatively, my goal is to have a 1 or 2 click option to update a bookmark to the current page, instead of having to rclick > edit > copy url > paste url > save.  The goal was to have an 'Update to current page' item in the bookmark context menu, but if anyone can think of another solution let me know.  I made a popup extension that can do this, but I'm looking for a way that stays in the bookmarks bar.

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that isnt possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [ContextType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType) doesn't include anything related with bookmarks, I believe you can't achieve that.

Maybe you can [override the default bookmark](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks), although you **can't change the special "Bookmarks Bar"**, but since you have taken over the default bookmarks, you could control how user updates bookmarks via the entry your provided, either through clicking page/browser action (See [Google Bookmarks Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik?hl=en-US)) or anything else.